# Is there a diagram of built-in classes?

Tags: common-lisp

Hyperspec will mention all the superclasses of the given class, but not any of those which inherit from the given class, so compiling an exhaustive list isn't easy. Does anyone know of a document that lists all built-in classes and their relationships?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at Greg Pfeil's chart of the Common Lisp Type Hierarchy at http://sellout.github.io/2012/03/03/common-lisp-type-hierarchy/

Comment: Yup, that covers it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Types diagram can be found in the Common Lisp Quick Reference (http://clqr.boundp.org) also.